# Sequential dot_product in OpenACC Fortran loop

Tags: fortran, openacc, pgi-accelerator

In a Fortran program, I have a large loop with several `dot_product` calls on small vectors generated within the loop:

```
program test
        implicit none

        real :: array1(2, 2), array2(2, 2), res(2)
        real :: subarray1(2), subarray2(2)
        integer :: i

        array1 = 1
        array2 = 2

        !$acc data copyin(array1, array2) copyout(res)
        !$acc kernels
        !$acc loop independent private(subarray1, subarray2)
        do i = 1, 2
                subarray1(:) = array1(:, i)
                subarray2(:) = array2(:, i)
                res(i) = dot_product(subarray1, subarray2)
        enddo
        !$acc end kernels
        !$acc end data

        print "(2(g0, x))", res
endprogram
```

When compiled with the PGI compiler, it seems that the accelerated implementation of `dot_product` uses accelerated loops, and hence prevents to accelerate the main loop better (on gang and vector):

```
test:
     11, Generating copyin(array1(:,:)) [if not already present]
         Generating copyout(res(:)) [if not already present]
         Generating copyin(array2(:,:)) [if not already present]
     14, Loop is parallelizable
         Generating Tesla code
         14, !$acc loop gang ! blockidx%x
         15, !$acc loop vector(32) ! threadidx%x
         17, !$acc loop vector(32) ! threadidx%x
             Generating implicit reduction(+:subarray1$r)
     14, CUDA shared memory used for subarray2,subarray1
     15, Loop is parallelizable
     17, Loop is parallelizable
```

As seen in the logs, it uses implicit reduction and shared memory for the loop private vectors.

Is there a way to force `dot_product` to run sequentially?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to force dot_product to run sequentially?

So long as you don't mind the array syntax being run sequentially as well, just add "gang vector" to the loop directive.

```
% cat test.f90
program test
        implicit none

        real :: array1(2, 2), array2(2, 2), res(2)
        real :: subarray1(2), subarray2(2)
        integer :: i

        array1 = 1
        array2 = 2

        !$acc data copyin(array1, array2) copyout(res)
        !$acc kernels loop gang vector private(subarray1, subarray2)
        do i = 1, 2
                subarray1(:) = array1(:, i)
                subarray2(:) = array2(:, i)
                res(i) = dot_product(subarray1, subarray2)
        enddo
        !$acc end data

        print "(2(g0, x))", res
endprogram
% nvfortran -acc -Minfo=accel test.f90
test:
     11, Generating copyin(array1(:,:)) [if not already present]
         Generating copyout(res(:)) [if not already present]
         Generating copyin(array2(:,:)) [if not already present]
     13, Loop is parallelizable
         Generating Tesla code
         13, !$acc loop gang, vector(32) ! blockidx%x threadidx%x
         14, !$acc loop seq
         16, !$acc loop seq
     13, Local memory used for subarray2,subarray1
     14, Loop is parallelizable
     16, Loop is parallelizable
```